# Acessing multiple anchor elements inside text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I have the following XPATH

```
//a[@class='product-cardstyles__Link-sc-1uwpde0-9 bSQmwP hyperlinkstyles__Link-j02w35-0 coaZwR']
```

This xpath, finds a lot of anchor tags similar to the following HTML sample

```
<a href="/produto/10669/acucar-refinado-da-barra-pacote-1kg" class="product-cardstyles__Link-sc-1uwpde0-9 bSQmwP hyperlinkstyles__Link-j02w35-0 coaZwR" font-size="16" font-family="primaryMedium">Açúcar Refinado DA BARRA Pacote 1kg</a>
```

What I want to do is not to acess it is href, it is to grab the following string inside the anchor elements?

```
Açúcar Refinado DA BARRA Pacote 1kg
```

Sample code of what I am currently doing

```
    elements_list = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='product-cardstyles__Link-sc-1uwpde0-9 bSQmwP hyperlinkstyles__Link-j02w35-0 coaZwR']"))
    print(elements_list)
    # How do I extract the text honhon?
```

If needed I could share the entire source code for reproduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need iterate the list and then get the `text` value.

```
elements_list = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='product-cardstyles__Link-sc-1uwpde0-9 bSQmwP hyperlinkstyles__Link-j02w35-0 coaZwR']"))
for element in elements_list:
    print(element.text)
```

---

if you want to get text values in a list use this.

```
print([element.text for element in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='product-cardstyles__Link-sc-1uwpde0-9 bSQmwP hyperlinkstyles__Link-j02w35-0 coaZwR']")))])
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

```py
print(element.text)
```